# Android App crashing and not working correctly on smaller devices

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-resources

Here is my problem , i created app for android and was always testing it on my phone with 480x800 dimensions, and app works great, in landscape and portrait mode. I used relative layout cause it seemed like the best good solution for a beginner like me. But now, i tried installing app on smaller device (lg optimus l3) and add is covering my buttons, landscape mode not showing buttons at all ..  i used density independent pixels for sizes of every aspect of layout but still it doesn't work . . any suggestions? is it possible to create folder layout specially for smaller devices ? Thank you for any help you can provide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your should take a look at [this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) and read it carefully.

Answering your question, yes, there are ways of having different layouts for different screen sizes and densities.